# How to get object values inside array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I received this data form{} from view in my controller ($rquest) 
How to get "product_id" values in product array with x items {} to use them in my controller ?

```
form: {
   id: null,
   sale_number: 2,
   client: null,
   products: [
      { product_id:1,description: null, quantity:1, price: 1}
      { product_id:2,description: null, quantity:1, price: 1}
      { product_id:3,description: null, quantity:1, price: 1}
      .....etc
   ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$request->products` and `foreach` them

```
foreach($request->products as $product)
{
    $product['product_id']
}
```

if you want to save them in an array then do this

```
$product_id_array = array();
foreach($request->products as $product)
{
    product_id_array[] = $product['product_id'];
}
```